# What is wrong with this access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, not-exists

Running the below query returns 0 records, but I would expect it to return 3.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    DW2_TV_DimStation_Id,
    DW2_OTT_DimStation_Id,
    Name,
    CoreTVCode,
    CoreOTTCode,
    StrataTVCode,
    HouseHolds,
    MaleSkew,
    FemaleSkew,
    AverageAge,
    AverageIncome,
    BroadReach,
    Description,
    Owner,
    Notes,
    timestamp,
    CreatedOn,
    ModifiedOn,
    Retired,
    1 AS Accepted
FROM
    Planning_DimStation AS src
WHERE
    src.[timestamp] = (
        SELECT
            MAX([timestamp])
        FROM
            Planning_DimStation AS src2
        WHERE
            src2.[ID] = src.[ID]
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1 
        FROM
            DimStation AS tgt
        WHERE
            tgt.[ID] = src.[ID]
    );
```

The part that breaks it is the `NOT EXISTS` statement.  If I delete the `NOT EXISTS` it works fine.

- Table 1: `Planning_DimStation`

  - Is an SQL table linked with 3 records in it. Source below.
- Table 2: `DimStation`

  - Is an Access table (pic of source UI below) that is empty

Could this be a silent fail caused by type missmatch?

Table 1:

```
    CREATE TABLE [Planning].[DimStation]
    (
        [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY,
        [DW2_TV_DimStation_Id] INT NULL,
        [DW2_OTT_DimStation_Id] INT NULL,
        [Name] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        [CoreTVCode] CHAR(5) NULL,
        [CoreOTTCode] CHAR(10) NULL,
        [StrataTVCode] CHAR(10) NULL,
        [HouseHolds] DECIMAL(5,2) NULL,
        [MaleSkew] DECIMAL(5,2) NULL,
        [FemaleSkew] DECIMAL(5,2) NULL,
        [AverageAge] INT NULL,
        [AverageIncome] DECIMAL(23,2) NULL,
        [BroadReach] BIT NULL,
        [Description] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
        [Owner] NVARCHAR(128) NULL,
        [Notes] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
        [timestamp] timestamp NOT NULL,
        [CreatedOn] DATETIME2(7) CONSTRAINT [df_Planning_DimStation_CreatedOn] DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL,
        [ModifiedOn] DATETIME2(7) CONSTRAINT [df_Planning_DimStation_ModifiedOn] DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL,
        [Retired] BIT CONSTRAINT [df_Planning_DimStation_Retired] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL
    )
    GO
```

Table 2:

[image]

Comment: ID fields between the two tables have different data types. That could very well be it.

Comment: I recommend changing your query to use a `JOIN` instead of using `WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT ... FROM query )`.

Comment: @Dai why? That's less explicit and often slower than a `Exists`

Comment: @ErikA It won't be slower than an `EXISTS`. It should actually be faster because the DBMS is free to choose its own way of filtering. As for being "explicit", that's subjective (I *prefer* JOINs because all of the data-sources being queried are in the `FROM` section instead of being in `WHERE` or `SELECT` where I only expect to see existing data-sources). If in doubt, add a comment to the query to explain what's happening.

Comment: @Dai Then you probably have limited experience using cross-database-engine queries in MS Access (such as this one). I've noted very substantial performance differences between joins and `EXIST` clauses, and these kind of queries often have poor performance, so it's not premature optimization. I've seen cases where it's an hours -> minutes difference. Of course, it's generally preferable to not query across multiple database engines whenever possible.

Comment: @ErikA I would like to see the Query Execution Plans (Access+JET can produce them, it's a hidden registry setting) of the cases where it's slower than a JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Joining on different data types tends to yield unexpected results.
To fix this, use casts.

A note is that Access doesn't allow nulls to be cast. So we need to work around that using `Nz` (same as `ISNULL` in T-SQL) and explicitly handling nulls.

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1 
    FROM
        DimStation AS tgt
    WHERE
        CLng(IIF(tgt.[ID] IS NULL, 0, tgt.ID)) = src.[ID] AND NOT tgt.ID IS NULL
);
```

Comment: `Nz` is a VBA function that's invoked by the Access database engine, it isn't part of Access' SQL implementation itself (so this query will not work when run outside of Access, such as in an OLE-DB or ODBC query). Instead of `Nz( value, default )` queries should use `IIF( value IS NULL, default )` - which shold also run faster as Access won't be invoking a VBA function for every row it tests.

Comment: @Dai Fair, since it should not actually be called for this example since there are 0 rows in the table, and this query won't be able to be executed over ODBC/OLEDB anyway since that doesn't support external data sources, I didn't really mind here, but using IIF is a better practice so I've adjusted it.